# Spring .NET, WCF and Singletons

Tags: wcf, spring.net

It appears there's some [issue](http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?t=5903) integrating Spring .NET with WCF for getting singleton semantics. I looked around a bit on the net but I couldn't find anything conclusive.

Has anybody used Spring.Net with a WCF service where the instance context mode has been set to Single, Concurrency Mode set to multiple and the object definition in spring configuration marked as a singleton?

Answer (score 1):

Check the Spring documentation :
http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/wcf.html

"The object must be declared as a 'prototype' object, i.e. not a singleton, in order to interact correctly with WCF instancing."

HTH

Comment: Does this also apply to the service's collaborating objects?  IOW, do my service dependencies also need to be marked as protoype?